# Firebase Facebook Twitter Providers getEmail null

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an Android app with Firebase. I authenticate user with Email, Facebook, Twitter accounts. The problem is I have the permissions for Facebook and Twitter getting the email.

I can get the email and in the Firebase console, I can see the related Emails for Facebook and Twitter. But in the app, I cannot get the email of Facebook and Twitter accounts. I looked at the all provider data of user.

Like follows:

```
user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
//First provider is firebase all the time
user.getProviderData().get(1).getProviderId() = "twitter.com"
user.getProviderData().get(1).getEmail() = null
user.getEmail() = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem Firebase has a option for "One account per email address". If it is disabled, the user (which other accounts will be linked) not getting any information on itself from the providers. All provider data stored in the providers. But if you enable the "One account per email address", it writes the related info on user and user.getEmail() returns the email from provider.

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct way [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
   //this will iterate through all providers
   user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {

   console.log("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId);
   console.log("  Provider-specific UID: "+profile.uid);
   console.log("  Name: "+profile.displayName);
   console.log("  Email: "+profile.email);
   console.log("  Photo URL: "+profile.photoURL);

   //this will get the details of twitter. check "google.com" for google..
   if(profile.providerId == "twitter.com"){
      String twitterUid = profile.uid;
      String twitterEmail = profile.email; 
      etc...
   }

  });

}
```

Comment: I am already doing these. I have just put the related part in here.

Comment: Then try to print the user object to console and check the data is there.

Comment: oops i mistook your question.. i thinks user object holds only a single provider. which ever is currently logged in.

Comment: No you are wrong. It holds at least one provider. Firebase provider always hold and if there any other provider, it holded additionally.

Comment: Okey. The edited answer is the way that I am doing already. I am aware of the firebase user data structure. What I am trying to say is; still no email even if I see them in the firebase console. I am wondering; I might need extra setttings to get the email.